# Slick. Select and then update selected rows

Tags: scala, slick

I want to select some rows, update them and return updated values, but I don't understand how can I do it with Slick. Here is an example. I want to select all tasks which are awaiting execution, lock them, change statuses to in progress and return updated tasks:

```
object Test {

  case class Task(id: Int, status: String)

  class TaskTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Task](tag, "tasks") {
    def id = column[Int]("id")
    def status = column[String]("status")

    def * = (id, status) <>(Task.tupled, Task.unapply)
  }

  val tasks = TableQuery[TaskTable]

  def selectWaitingTasksAndChangeStatus(): Seq[Task] = {
    tasks.filter(_.status === "awaitingExecution").forUpdate 
    // Here I want to change status to "inProgress" and 
    // return tasks to client code with "inProgress" status
  }

}
```

Comment: What version of Slick are you using?

Comment: @Paweł Jurczenko 3.2.0-M1

Answer (score 0):

Is this the thing you're looking for?

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

def selectWaitingTasksAndChangeStatus(): Seq[Task] = {
  val selectAction = tasks.filter(_.status === "inProgress").result
  val updateAction = tasks.filter(_.status === "awaitingExecution").map(_.status).update("inProgress")
  val combinedAction = for {
    tasksBeforeUpdate <- selectAction
    _                 <- updateAction
    tasksAfterUpdate  <- selectAction
  } yield tasksAfterUpdate.diff(tasksBeforeUpdate)

  Await.result(db.run(combinedAction.transactionally), Duration.Inf)
}
```

Since you'd like to get `Seq[Task]` from that method, you have to synchronously wait for the result from the database. Asynchronous solution would require `Future[Seq[Task]]` as the returned type.

Comment: Thank you, but not exactly I think. I need to select only tasks which status was changed, not all tasks that in progress. So I think I need to select tasks that waiting execution, lock them, update status and return them to client. And lock is important because I suppose although we have a transaction here if we do not lock selected rows and another process does the same thing at the same time I might end up with tasks selected twice. So I need to use select for update which as I understend is available only in 3.2.*

Comment: I haven't used Slick 3.2 since it's not yet production ready. I have updated my answer though, which hopefully solves your problem now. It takes all the tasks before and after the update, and calculates the difference between those two (which effectively returns only the tasks that were updated in that transaction).